# Which mouth form is the close one to pronounce the R

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, accent, american-accent

I am trying to learn American R, I have a problem, which is the R becomes like "O" in the begging of the word like

Reall-> I say: "Oreally" with a very very very small "O".

So I tried to change my lips, and I found that there are two situation for the lips,

#### The first one is

[image]

and if you look from side, it looks like this:
[image]

#### The second one is when you make your lips as you open them a little bit

[image]

I know probably neither of them is correct, but which one is more closer to the correct " American R"

Comment: You'll want to concentrate more on your tongue position, I think.

Comment: I think it spends on which 'r' sound you're after. The initial R in *red* or the R in 'are'.  The second can be made without moving your lips at all if you start out kind of slightly open-lipped like just normal breathing through your mouth.  The first R can be formed using a lip shape akin to standard whistling and then,since that would be considered slightly exaggerated, relax the lips a bit but not so much that you lose the R sound.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'd recommend you to try to relax your lips completely when practicing your AmE /r/. Don't try to make it flat, or round, or form any shapes. (Don't forget to keep your lips alive, too. They are part of your face, and a face is not a mask. :-) Let your pronunciation flow naturally, work on your tongue to ensure that it sounds right, and your lips will form their own shape automatically. Have fun learning English!

Comment: When I say the word "really" at the beginning of a sentence, I find that I am very nearly saying "oReally" with the tiniest bit of an "o" possible, so you may be on the right track.  Also, my wife thinks I'm insane after I said the phrase, "really fast" about a dozen times in a row to nobody in particular.  The same word in the middle of a sentence doesn't have the initial sound because my mouth isn't adjusting from a fully relaxed state but instead from the end of the previous word.

Comment: @JasonPatterson that is a relief, thanks. I have been trying to pronounce the American "R" for like three months, and yet no success :( :( maybe because I don't have anyone to talk to in English, or maybe because i don't have an American friend, or probably because I am a very bad learner :X :X.

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli I'm sure you know, but *using* any foreign language is the real key to learning to speak it well.  If you've gotten to the point where you're concerned about a particular difficult sound in English, you're clearly not a bad learner.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think either of the images you posted look all right. I might say the bottom one is a bit more natural, simply because looking in the mirror, it isn't usually a very large movement of the lips for me. As others have mentioned, the tongue position is the most important to get right for an understandable "r" sound. You have a good ear, though: this lip rounding during an "r" sound at the start of a word, like the lip rounding during an "o" or a "w" sound, is a well-documented feature of many people's pronunciation of English.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to raise up ur tounge like the second picture you share, and stick it to the top of your mouth which I think called it In Englishe alveolar...I am not sure concerning the word I mentioned but try once and do ur very best...
the best way for learning prounanciation is practise

Comment: There are lots of different tongue positions for AmE /r/, by the way.  Different people make the sound in different ways.  What's important is that you find a way that works for you and sounds right.